# Are there wisteria tunnels close to Tokyo?

Tags: japan, nature-and-wildlife, tokyo

[r/natureisfuckinglit](https://redd.it/cii2zi) asseverates this is [Kawachi Wisteria Garden](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Kawachi+Wisteria+Garden/@33.8329124,130.7884743,16z/data=!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x3543c8aab79722b9:0xfc838ba236e0f48a!2sKawachi+Wisteria+Garden!8m2!3d33.832531!4d130.7919889!3m4!1s0x3543c8aab79722b9:0xfc838ba236e0f48a!8m2!3d33.832531!4d130.7919889) in [Kitakyushu, Fukuoka, Japan](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Kawachi+Wisteria+Garden/@33.8305257,130.7846718,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x3543c8aab79722b9:0xfc838ba236e0f48a!8m2!3d33.832531!4d130.7919889). Link to pic beneath.

Fukuoka is too far. Can I see something like this near Tokyo? I don't want just  a [single tree](https://redd.it/ah1fka).

[image]

Comment: https://mymodernmet.com/wisteria-tree-tunnels/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. The [Ashikaga Flower Park](https://www.ashikaga.co.jp/english/) is within [day trip distance](https://goo.gl/maps/4pERaUV89HBLwJ4WA) from Tokyo, and has a wisteria tunnel (as well as some other very impressive non-tunnel wisteria.)

I've been there during peak wisteria and I think it's well worth the visit, but be prepared for some serious crowds (easily accessible to you from Tokyo means easily accessible for everyone from Tokyo!)